# Tradingview does not work properly with the RSI condition

Tags: pine-script

My full code is:

```
//@version=4

strategy("test", overlay=true, initial_capital=10000, pyramiding=10)

src = close

days = input(title='days', type=input.integer, defval=7)

upper_shadow = close >= open? (high - close):(high - open)
lower_shadow = close >= open? (open - low):(close - low)
body = close >= open? (close - open):(open - close)

day_open = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
day_body = security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", sma(body, days), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

//6 hours
heikinashi_open = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), "360", open, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
heikinashi_close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), "360", close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
change_close = security(heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), "360", abs(change(close)) , lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

plot(day_body)
plot(change_close)
    

if change_close > day_body 

    if (heikinashi_close > heikinashi_open) and (rsi(close, 14) < 30)
        strategy.entry("long entry", strategy.long)
    if rsi(close, 14) > 70
        strategy.exit("exit L", "long entry")
```

The problem is on backtest, TradingView is not making the long entry with condition `rsi(close, 14) < 30`.

Here is the proof, the RSI of the bar is obviously greater than 30:
[image]

- I'm using the 5-min timeframe.

Is it a bug of TradingView? The if condition is not valid!

Comment: calling values that are updating during the candle with a security() function + lookahead argument  will lead the script to repaint and produce different results on historical vs real-time candles. There is an article in the Tradingview Help Center regarding the issue, can't post the link otherwise mods will hide the comment :)

Comment: @e2e4 thanks, this should be an adopted answer.